# scrlayer-scrpage with \pagestyle{empty}

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

My table of contents is two-sided but I don't want to have a letterhead on the second side. I don't know why but `\pagestyle{empty}` doesn't do the job in my case.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % doesn't work

\tableofcontents

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\lehead{\pagemark} 
\cehead{\headmark} 
\cohead{\headmark} 
\rohead{\pagemark} 

\chapter{bla}
\blindtext[10]
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\chapter{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\chapter{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\end{document}
```

**Additional Information**

If `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` is deactivated `\pagestyle{empty}` produces the desired result.

Comment: So you want to change the toc pagestyle?

Comment: Well, yes. I don't want to have the page number and the toc title on the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles% or \clearpairofpagestyles?
\ohead{\pagemark}
\chead{\headmark}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{empty}}% settings for the last page of TOC, LOF, LOT etc.

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that there is a page number in the footer of the chapter pages including the first page of the TOC. If you want to remove this page number too, you can use either `\clearpairofpagestyles` instead `\clearmainofpairofpagestyles` or you can redefine `\chapterpagestyle` to `empty`. By default `\chapterpagestyle` is `plain`.

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

affects LOF, LOT and other lists controlled by package `tocbasic`, too. If you want to restrict the changes to TOC use

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\pagestyle{empty}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark[chapter]{chapter} 
\lehead{\pagemark} 
\cehead{\headmark} 
\cohead{\headmark} 
\rohead{\pagemark} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % doesn't work

\tableofcontents


\chapter{bla}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\blindtext[10]
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\chapter{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\chapter{bla}

\chapter{bla}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, just remove `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` where you have it (last page of toc). It is pointless anyway.